# Multi level growth model - modelling the covariance structure

Tags: autoregressive, growth-model

I am performing a multi level growth model in R with rank as the DV, seasons since draft as the time-based predictor and a random effect for position (intercept and slope). I am attempting to model the covariance structure using corAR1 given the time points of seasons since draft are equally spaced.

```
ARModel<-lme(CD.points ~ Seasons.since.draft,
random=~Seasons.since.draft|Position,method="ML",
data=mydata,na.action=na.exclude, correlation = corAR1(0,
form=~Seasons.since.draft|Position))
```

This produces an error;

```
Error in Initialize.corAR1(X[[i]], ...) : 
covariate must have unique values within groups for "corAR1" objects
```

Please see an example of my data below;

```
CD.points    Seasons.since.draft    Position
32                 5                   3
31                 5                   3
24                 5                   3
21                 5                   2
66                 6                   2
63                 6                   1
40                 6                   4
24                 6                   3
32                 6                   2
10                 6                   2
10                 6                   1
82                 7                   1
61                 7                   1
```

Why am I getting this error? is there a way to get around this? As you can see, the values within seasons since draft and position are not unique. The only way for them to be unique would be if I included an additional variable - round (e.g. round 11). (that may be completely off track but I am trying to figure out what R is telling me in the error).

Thank you!